# Cannot Use Cascading Dropdowns When Using trAppend by JavaScript in ASP.NET Core

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I working on Invoice Details in ASP.NET Core 6 and this is my problem. So I create a view allowed user invoice the product. Here the view [Invoice products](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VZ0R8.png). User want to invoice the product they have to click plus button and the new row will appear like this [new row product](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ODhw.png). So I using cascading dropdowns to select the color of product, so when i change the product, the color select box will change. The problem is its doesn't work but when I move the select box outside the  @using (Html.BeginForm()) its work correctly. I belived it because the javascipt about the append cause cascading dropdowns can't work correctly.

```
@model Invoice
@{
    Layout = "~/Areas/Admin/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";

    IEnumerable<ProductItem> lstProduct = ViewBag.ListProduct as IEnumerable<ProductItem>;
}

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function () {
        $(".datepicker").datepicker();
    });
</script>

<h2>@ViewData["Title"]</h2>

<div class="card">
    <div class="card-body">
        @using (Html.BeginForm())
        {
            <div class="form-group row pb-2">
                <div class=" col-md-6">
                    <label class="col-form-label font-weight-bold" asp-for="SupplierId">Supplier</label>
                    <select  asp-for="SupplierId" class="form-control" asp-items="@ViewBag.Supplier"></select>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <label class="col-form-label font-weight-bold">Created Date</label>
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <div class="input-group-prepend">
                            <span class="input-group-text"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></span>
                        </div>
                        <input type="datetime-local" asp-for="CreateDate" class="form-control" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="clearfix"></div>
            </div>
       
            <table class="tblInvoiceDetail table  table-hover">
            
                <tr class="trAppend table-borderless">
                    <td>
                        <select class="ddlProductItemsId" id="productList" asp-items="ViewBag.Product">
                            
                        </select>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <select id="colorId"></select>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <select name="" class="ddlSize" id="sizeId">
                        </select>
                    </td>

                    <td>
                        <input name="" class="txtPrice" value="0" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input name="" class="txtQuanity" value="0"/>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="button" class="btnDelete btn btn-danger" style="width: 2em; height:2em;" value="-" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="trFirstChild" data-id="-1">
                    <td class="col-form-label font-weight-bold">Product</td>
                    <td class="col-form-label font-weight-bold">Color</td>
                    <td class="col-form-label font-weight-bold">Size</td>
                    <td class="col-form-label font-weight-bold">Price</td>
                    <td class="col-form-label font-weight-bold">Quantity</td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <div class="form-group row">
                <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-sm-6">
                    <input type="button" value="+" class="btn btn-sm btn-success font-weight-bold mr-2" style="width: 3em; height:2em;" id="btnAdd" />
                    <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary font-weight-bold " id="btnNhapHang" />
                </div>
            </div>
        }
    </div>
</div>
<style>
    .trAppend {
        display: none;
    }
</style>

@section Scripts
{
    <script>
    
        $(document).ready(function () {
            GetProductByColor();
        });

        $("#productList").change(function () {
            GetProductByColor();
        });

        function GetProductByColor() {
            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("GetProductByColor", "Invoice")',
                type: 'GET',
                data: {
                    id: $("#productList").val()
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    $('#colorId').empty();
                    $(data).each(function (index, item) {
                        $('#colorId').append('<option value="' + item.productItemsId + '">' + item.productItemsId + '</option>');
                    });
                }
            });
        }
    </script>
<script>
        $('#btnAdd').click(function () {
            var id_last = $(".tblInvoiceDetail").find("tr:last-child").attr("data-id");
            i = parseInt(id_last) + 1;

            var tdcontent = $(".trAppend").html();
            var trcontent = "<tr class=\"trAppended\" data-id=\"" + i + "\">" + tdcontent + "<\tr>";
            $(".tblInvoiceDetail").append(trcontent);
            loadIDCard();
        });

        $("body").delegate(".btnDelete", "click", function () {
            $(this).closest(".trAppended").remove();
            UpdateID();
        });

        $("#btnConfirm").click(function () {
            if (reviewPrice() == false) {
                return false;
            }

            if (reviewQuanity() == false) {
                return false;
            }

            var totalPrice = 0;
            var totalQuanity = 0;

            $(".tblInvoiceDetail .trAppended").each(function () {


                var Price = parseFloat($(this).find(".txtPrice").val()) || 0;
                var Quanity = parseInt($(this).find(".txtQuanity").val()) || 0;


                totalPrice += Price;
                totalQuanity += Quanity;
            });

            if (totalPrice <= 0 && totalQuanity <= 0) {
                alert("Error input !");
                return false;
            }
        });

        function loadIDCard() {
            $(".trAppended").each(function () {
                var id = $(this).attr("data-id");

                var nameSize = "[" + id + "].SizeId";
                var nameIdProduct = "[" + id + "].ProductItemsId";
                var namePriceImport = "[" + id + "].Price";
                var nameQuanityImport = "[" + id + "].Quanity";

                $(this).find(".ddlSize").attr("name", nameSize);
                $(this).find(".ddlProductItemsId").attr("name", nameIdProduct);
                $(this).find(".txtPrice").attr("name", namePriceImport);
                $(this).find(".txtQuanity").attr("name", nameQuanityImport);
            })
        };

        function UpdateID() {
            var id_last = $(".tblInvoiceDetail").find("trFirstChild").attr("data-id");
            i = parseInt(id_last) + 1;

            $(".trAppended").each(function () {
                var id = i = $(this).attr("data-id");

                var nameSize = "[" + id + "].SizeId";
                var nameIdProduct = "[" + id + "].ProductItemsId";
                var namePriceImport = "[" + id + "].Price";
                var nameQuanityImport = "[" + id + "].Quanity";

                $(this).find(".ddlSize").attr("name", nameSize);
                $(this).find(".ddlProductItemsId").attr("name", nameIdProduct);
                $(this).find(".txtPrice").attr("name", namePriceImport);
                $(this).find(".txtQuanity").attr("name", nameQuanityImport);
            });
        }

        function reviewPrice() {
            var bl = true;

            $(".txtPrice").each(function () {
                var value = $(this).val();
                if (isNaN(value) == true) {
                    alert("Invalid Price!");
                    bl = false;
                    return bl;
                }
            });

            return bl;
        }

  
</script>
}
```

Why when the product and color select list in the form cant use the cassading dropdown but outside its works.Is there anyway combine these 2 functions and work?.  I will appreciated any instructions. Thanks for spending time reading my problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally it is a script-running-order issue. The event handler isn't bound to these new instances of productList when you click the + button to add dynamically. You can modify the event and here is a sample.

**1.Controller**

```
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        var lstProduct = new List<ProductItem>
        {
            new ProductItem { Id = 1, Name = "Product 1" },
            new ProductItem { Id = 2, Name = "Product 2" }
            // Add more products as needed
        };

        var colors = new List<ColorItem>
        {
            new ColorItem { Id = 0, ColorName = "Sample" },
        };

        ViewBag.ListProduct = lstProduct;
        ViewBag.Colors = colors;
        return View();
    }

    public IActionResult GetColorsForProduct(int id)
    {
        var colors = new List<object> { };
        // Mock data - replace with actual data fetching logic
        if (id == 1)
        {
            colors = new List<object>
            {
                new { value = "Red", text = "Red" },
                new { value = "Blue", text = "Blue" }
            };
        }
        else
        {
            colors = new List<object>
            {
                new { value = "Yellow", text = "Yellow" },
                new { value = "Black", text = "Black" }
            };
        }
        return Json(colors);
    }
```

**2.Your View**

```
<tr class="trAppend table-borderless">
    <td>
        <select class="form-control ddlProductItemsId" id="productList">
            <option value="">Select a Product</option>
            @foreach (var product in ViewBag.ListProduct as IEnumerable<ProductItem>)
            {
                <option value="@product.Id">@product.Name</option>
            }
        </select>
    </td>
    <td>
        <select class="form-control colorSelect" id="colorId">
            <option value="">Select a Color</option>
            @foreach (var color in ViewBag.Colors as IEnumerable<ColorItem>)
            {
                <option value="@color.Id">@color.ColorName</option>
            }
        </select>
    </td>
    ...
</tr>
```

**3.Your Script in View**

```
@section Scripts
{
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>
    <script>
    
        $(document).ready(function () {
            
        });

        $(document).on('change', '.ddlProductItemsId', function () {
            // Finds the nearest row (<tr>) to find the color dropdown specific to this product dropdown
            var $row = $(this).closest('tr'); 
            GetProductByColor($(this).val(), $row.find('#colorId'));
        });

        function GetProductByColor(productId, $colorDropdown) {
            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("GetColorsForProduct", "Home")',
                type: 'GET',
                data: { id: productId },
                success: function (data) {
                    $colorDropdown.empty().append('<option value="">Select a Color</option>');
                    $(data).each(function (index, item) {
                        $colorDropdown.append($('<option></option>').val(item.value).html(item.text));
                    });
                }
            });
        }
    </script>
    ...
}
```

Then you can get cascading dropdown work.

[image]
[image]